# My rabbit is bleeding!

Tags: rabbits

I took my bunny out of his cage so he could run around, and he somehow got under my fists when I was leaning over the cage to clean it. My bunny flailed around wildly, and part of his fur and skin got ripped out on top of his nail. Help!!! What should I do!!???

Comment: visit a vet maby.

Comment: No maybe, go see a vet about this!